# Batching or sending multiple rows of records in single event to event hub/kafka from spark structured streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I am building a spark structured streaming job where I am trying to batch/send multiple rows of data in a single event.

Basically trying to see if we can reduce the number of message being transferred over the wire to kafka or event hub.

I have tried collect_list() to create json array and other options to send batches of events to event hub. But its taking more time to create the list and send it to event hub.

Also, have tried the batch.size() and linger.ms() options available on kafka producer side (With Kafka end point of event hub) and even there I dont see much improvement on the performance.

How can we batch or group multiple rows of data in a dataframe in single event and send it to event hub or kafka from spark structured streaming job ?

Below is a sample code i am using.
collect_list() to create a json array instead of sending events one by one.
And batch.size() and linger.ms() to batch and send events instead of sending one by one.

```
df
.writeStream.foreachBatch {
(batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
batchDF
selectExpr("CAST(collect_list(to_json(struct(*))) AS STRING) AS value")
.write
.format("kafka")
.option("topic", topic)
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer)
.option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_PATH)
.option("kafka.batch.size", 20000)
.option("kafka.linger.ms", 0)
.option("kafka.compression.type", "lz4")
.save()}
.start
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you've been using?

Comment: Yes, have added a sample in the question

Comment: So, batch.size and linger.ms (or any other client config) would not be responsible for grouping the events, only the collect_list is doing that. Those control how frequently the client sends data. However, I'm not sure why you couldn't flatMap/select with the `collect_list(to_json` the original df, then use `writeStream.format("kafka")`

Comment: Overall your code does what you want, so maybe you should clarify how you are measuring network traffic and specifically what your target is. If it's overall network bandwidth, then sending JSON/text rather than a more compact binary format is probably the largest problem

Comment: Thank you, Actually, the spark application is performing slower and wanted to see if we can batch/group multiple rows in single event.  that way , we will reduce the network transfer of millions of events..

Comment: Right, and that's what you're doing, however querying each dataframe batch then collapsing it into a single row certainly won't make it faster. Kafka can handle millions of events per second just fine, so seems like you have some other bottleneck (number of Spark executors or their cpu/memory configs, perhaps?). Checkpoints also slow down the code